# React native app screen flickering. when changing one screen to another screen, 2nd screen is flickering

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-native-screens

Current Installed Versions -

```
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
"accordion-collapse-react-native": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
```

Video link - `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jNV_HdE8MHb62VQf5hjq6654yuCKLBXy/view?usp=sharing`

CODE :

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you share your code and the screens where you're encountering the issue

Comment: @RodSar
https://drive.google.com/file/d/175XyYtFz_exEPj_5nT3OAMzz4-CcBH62/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can watch the video ```https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jNV_HdE8MHb62VQf5hjq6654yuCKLBXy/view?usp=sharing```
thanks @RodSar

Comment: any update on this issue?